# How can you display access permissions of a file or folder using PowerShell using cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions, operating-system, ntfs

please help me in this question of operating system

Answer (score 1):

To display access permissions of a file or a folder using PowerShell, you can use something like this:

```
Get-Item D:\Data | Get-NTFSAccess
Get-NTFSAccess -Path D:\Data
```

Which will give you results which look like this:

[image]

Reference:  [Reading the permissions of a single item](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/)